# Read data from external database and display it in webpart

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

I need to create a sharepoint 2010 webpart and I have get particular records from a external database table and display it in the webpart.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into Business Connectivity Services (BCS). Basically, you need to get SharePoint Designer and connect to the site you want to make an external list on, create the "external content type" and then once you have the external list working, SharePoint Enterprise has webparts to bring that forward to a page.

References:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819133.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee557704(v=office.14).aspx
http://sharepoint-videos.com/sp10-business-data-web-parts/

Answer (score 0):

Open VS2010 -> create new project -> sharepoint 2010 Empty project Template -> Add you site URL

Right click on Project in Solution Explorer -> and new item -> Select Sharepoint Visiual Webpart

in Webpart .ascx file design your UI ->  and in .ascx.cs file Write your Code about Load Data and other operation on Database Table.

Now Right click on Project -> select Deploy Option.

Now Go to  your site -> edit page -> insert Webpart -> select your Visual webpart from custom Folder.